# Convergence of $\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{n\ln\left(n\right)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is this convergent or not?
$$\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{n\ln\left(n\right)}$$

I tried using the ratio test but the limit is giving me 1, which doesn't help me. I don't think I'm supposed to use the integral test, since we haven't studied it.

Comment: But the integral test? U-sub the ln...so easy...

Comment: HINT: $$\ln(1)=0$$

Comment: @imranfat I specified that I'm not supposed to use it.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner That's what I also thought, but I was kind of inclined to believe that the OP made a typo, otherwise this question is not so interesting anymore :)

Comment: @MikhaelM I didn't read well. But....This is just  kind of silly, but obviously not your fault. However, using the integral test, you can see that the series is divergent. Maybe you can use that result to find a different way to "work" towards your answer. Also, would you mind changing the starting value to $n=2$. ?

Comment: @imranfat yup, my bad, starting value is 2. Still trying to look for alternative methods of proving divergence now.

Answer (score 6):

If you are familiar with Cauchy Condensation Test, the condens series becomes 
$$\sum_{n} 2^n \frac{1}{2^n \ln (2^n)}$$

If not, you can use the idea of the test:

$$\frac{1}{2 \ln2 } \geq \frac{1}{2 \ln 2 }  \\
\frac{1}{3 \ln 3 } \geq \frac{1}{4 \ln 2^2 }  \\
\frac{1}{4 \ln 4 } \geq \frac{1}{4 \ln 2^2 }  \\
\frac{1}{5 \ln 5 } \geq \frac{1}{8 \ln 2^3 }  \\
.....\\
\frac{1}{2^n \ln 2^n } \geq \frac{1}{2^n \ln 2^n } $$

By adding you get
$$s_{2^n} \geq \frac{1}{2 \ln 2 } +\frac{1}{2 \ln 2^2 } +...+\frac{1}{2 \ln 2^n }=\frac{1}{2 \ln 2} (1+\frac12+\frac13+...+\frac1n)$$

Answer (score 3):

Define $x_n$ as :
$$x_n=\frac1{n\log n}\implies 2^nx_{2^n}=\frac{2^n}{2^n\log2^n}=\frac1{\log 2}\frac1n$$

You should be familiar with the condensation test.

Comment: Yup, we did study the condensation test. I'm looking into it now, thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help !

Answer (score 2):

People are mentioning the Cauchy Condensation Test, without saying what it is. Assuming you're *not* familiar with it, as a lot of people are not:

If $x_n>0$ and $x_{n+1}\le x_n$ then $\sum x_n<\infty$ if and only if $\sum_k2^kx_{2^k}<\infty$. Proving this is a good exercise; as has been pointed out, it shows your series diverges.

Comment: Thank you! I was familiar with the condensation test(as in, we did study it) but never actually used it so far.

Comment: It's a Good Thing (and if it's something you've covered it's surely what was intended for this problem). A person should be able to study sums without integrals...

Comment: Of course nobody says what it is, because there is no need to, since it's  always part of a handful of convergence criteria taught to first year undergrads in calculus.. As nobody ever feels the need to expand on $p$-series when they use it to provide bounds, why should there be need for  an explanation in this case?

Comment: Erm, it's _not_ always part of that course. It should be.