# Determine convergence of series with natural logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to determine the convergence of the series below: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(n+1)}{(n^2+2)\ln(n+3)}}$$

I've tried comparison test, Cauchy-condesation, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Compare it with https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1522832/42969

Comment: Applying Cauchy-condensation gives me $ln(2^n+3)$ and I can not get the n out of the log

Comment: A general strategy is to compare with an easier series, such as the one Martin mentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{n+1}{(n^2+2)\ln(n+3)}} \ge \sum_{n=3}^{\infty}{\frac{n}{2\cdot n^2 \cdot\ln(2n)}} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{ n\ln(2n)}}
$$
Now, by the [Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) we have that
$$
\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{ n\ln(2n)}}
$$
converges iff
$$
\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}{\frac{2^n}{ 2^n\ln(2\cdot 2^{n})}}
$$
converges.
But
$$
\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}{\frac{2^n}{ 2^n\ln(2\cdot2^{n})}} =\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{ (n+1)\ln(2)}} = \frac{1}{\ln(2)}\cdot\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{ n+1}} = +\infty 
$$
by the divergence of the harmonic series. It follows that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{n+1}{(n^2+2)\ln(n+3)}} \ge \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{ n\ln(2n)}} = +\infty.
$$

Comment: Thanks, I have a question, could I also use the integral test to show that $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{nln(2n)}} $ diverges ?

Comment: @Kain yes you can. The integral corresponding to that series is $$\int^{\infty}_3\frac{1}{n\ln(2n)}\text{ d}n$$ simply do a $u$ sub with $u=\ln(2n)$ and the integrand becomes $\frac1u$, which will diverge.

Comment: Yes. Then to prove that $\int_3^\infty \frac{1}{x \ln(2x)} \mathrm{d}x$ you could make the change of variables $x = e^u$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the integral test, it is trivial to show that $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}\frac{1}{n\ln n}$$ diverges. We may match indices with this from your series by doing the following
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(n+1)}{(n^2+2)\ln(n+3)}}=\frac{2}{3\ln4}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\frac{(n+1)}{(n^2+2)\ln(n+3)}}
$$
By taking the limit comparison test, we can show that the behavior of the two summands $\dfrac{1}{n\ln n}$ and $\dfrac{n+1}{(n^2+1)\ln(n+1)}$ have the exact same behavior: the rational powers on the latter cancel to match the behavior of $\frac1n$, while the constant in the logarithm vanishes at infinity to match the behavior of $\frac1{\ln n}$.

Thus $$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(n+1)}{(n^2+2)\ln(n+3)}}
$$ diverges

Comment: This is also a good solution thanks !!