# Determine whether the complex power series converges at a point

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

I need to determine if a series $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(z-1+i)^{2n-1}}{5^n(n+1)ln^3(n+1)}$$ converges at a point $z_1 = -1$

After substituting the point, I got: $$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(i - 2)^{2n-1}}{5^n(n+1)ln^3(n+1)} $$
And I do not know what to do next. I have heard that it is necessary to split this series into two, one with real coefficients, the other with complex ones. But here I don't see any way to break up this row like that. Can I investigate for convergence here using the root test ($\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$)?

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{(i-2)^{2n-1}}{5^n(n+1)ln^3(n+1)}\right|} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\left| \frac{(i-2)^{2n}}{(i-2)5^n} \right|} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{|i-2|^2}{5\sqrt{5}} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{5}{5\sqrt{5}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Therefore it converges.

Comment: What does the ratio test tell you?

Comment: @Aruralreader, the ratio test gives 1, which means that it does not give an answer about the convergence/divergence of the series at this point

Comment: @Aruralreader, in general, to begin with, I am interested in the question, can I apply the signs of convergence in this way? Or do I need to split the series into two parts, with imaginary coefficients and with real ones, and apply to them

Comment: Maybe worthwhile to study https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522832/convergence-of-sum-n-2-infty-frac1n-ln-leftn-right.

Answer (score -1):

To prove the series converges prove that the series $\sum_{n\ge 1} z^n/n$ converges on $|z| = 1, z \ne 1$, now put $z = (i-2)^2/5$ to conclude

Comment: I can prove it using root test: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{z^n/n} = |z|$. and for convergence it is necessary that it be less than 1. Therefore $|z| < 1$. But how did you get $z = (i - 2)^2/5$? I thing it is $\frac{(i-2)^2}{|i-2|}$ but why?

Answer (score -1):

$\mid-1-(1-i)\mid=\sqrt5.$

Thus we need a radius of convergence $\ge\sqrt 5.$

By Cauchy-Hadamard,  $$r=\frac1{\limsup\mid a_n\mid ^{1/n}}=\limsup \mid5^n(n+1)\ln^3(n+1)\mid ^{\frac 1{2n-1}}=\sqrt5$$

$\therefore $ we're on the boundary.

Something more needs to be done,  and you have done that,  with the root test.

The series converges at $z=-1.$

Comment: Your computation is incorrect since the radius of convergence is $\sqrt 5$ as $5$ appears in denominator in $a_n$ so $1/$ takes it up